# Plotly: How to draw multiple lines in the same plot with cufflinks

Tags: python, plotly, cufflinks

As described in title, I want to draw an auxiliary line on my original graph. I know it can be down using matplotlib or plotly, but I am wondering if cufflinks can do this as it is easier to use.
My original code is like this:

```
df.iplot(x='online_rop',y='offline_rop',kind='scatter',mode='markers+text',text='province')
```

I want to draw another line `y=x` on the same graph. How to do this?

Comment: I am not well-versed with cufflinks, but is it possible to store the plot (say as `fig = df.iplot(...)`), and add a line onto it by using `.iplot` again (`fig.iplot`) by passing a dataframe with two columns having identical values for plotting `y=x`?

Comment: Good idea! I can do this by adding another column.